# AWS SDK for Windows Phone 8 and Windows Store app

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, aws-sdk

I am working on a **Windows Phone 8** and **Windows Store app** that involves in **Amazon Web Services** (AWS). Is there an official AWS SDK available for these platforms?

I found AWS SDKs for iPhone and Android
http://aws.amazon.com/mobile/

But I am unable to locate a AWS SDK for the Microsoft Mobile platforms.

I also found Amazon SDK for .NET (http://aws.amazon.com/net/) but the AWSSDK.dll in this package is not compatible with WP8/Windows Store.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS released a preview of the AWS SDK for .NET last night which includes support for Windows Phone 8 and Windows Store Apps. You can find the details [on the .NET page](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet)

Answer (score 2):

There is a open source AWS SDK for Windows Phone: https://github.com/Microsoft-Interop/AWS-SDK-for-WP

But if that Amazon SDK for .NET does not work for Windows Store apps, than there is no sdk yet.

(You could theoretically take the source code for the Windows Phone one and make it compatible to Windows Store apps. Since most code written for Windows Phone should easily be transferable to Windows Store apps)

Comment: Thanks for the update, I was already doing a POC on the AWS-WP7-SDK. Other than the fact that its not been updated in a while, it worked well for my requirement of AWS S3 file uploads using PutRequestObject. I think the only option is to convert this code as a PCL so that I can use it from both WP8 & Windows 8 Store app. I am not sure why there is no support or official SDK from Amazon for these platforms.